# CSS хак или отдельный CSS для Opera

Tags: css, opera

Подскажите, какие сейчас существуют CSS хаки для Оперы v 65.0.3467.72 или как задать отдельный css для неё? Интересует именно для Opera, поэтом универсальные затрагивающие Хром, Яндекс и тд. - не подойдут

Comment: Ну и чем она не угодила? Почти наверняка никаких.

Comment: Но зачем, если опера это тот же самый хром?

Comment: К сожалению в Опере вёрстка немного стала отличаться, после обновления до последней версии. Поэтому и ищется какое-либо решение для Оперы